# Best way to insert data into specific column

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a table that have few column and i want to insert data only in certain column. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your other columns should be able to accept null data. You only need to give the values of the columns in which you want to insert data.For example if you want to insert data in only the first  column,then:

`Insert Into table-name(Column 1,Column 2) values ("value 1","");`

but remember, column 2 should be able to accept null data otherwise it wont work.

Comment: i dont want to use the column name,instead i want to use the column position. something like using index

Comment: Do you know the position of the column? you can skip the column names in the insert command and write it as: `insert into table-name values ("value 1", "" );` this will also work

Comment: let say there is a loop. so the the first loop it will insert data into 1st column second loop into second column and so on. how do i do that

Comment: you just need to check which iteration of the loop you are running.When the iteration equals the position of the column in which you want to insert the data only then insert the data.